# Installing Atom:::Terminal-Plus in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, atom

I'm trying to install Terminal-Plus (a Atom plugin) in Ubuntu 16.04. So I do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
sudo apt install npm
sudo npm install pty.js
sudo npm install npm -g
npm -v
```

returns: 3.5.2. Is this okay?

Then, I do:

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
sudo apm install fonts
```

Then, I do:

```
sudo apm install terminal-plus
```

and I get:

```
Installing terminal-plus to /home/me/.atom/packages ✗
> pty.js@0.3.0 install /tmp/apm-install-dir-116511-5876-r9x5dq/node_modules/terminal-plus/node_modules/pty.js
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
> pty.js@0.3.0 postinstall /tmp/apm-install-dir-116511-5876-r9x5dq/node_modules/terminal-plus/node_modules/pty.js
> node scripts/post-install.js
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/apm-install-dir-116511-5876-r9x5dq/node_modules/terminal-plus/node_modules/pty.js/scripts/post-install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/opt/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/opt/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/me/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/me/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-116511-5876-wgbgxq/package.tgz" "--target=0.36.8" "--arch=x64"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! pty.js@0.3.0 postinstall: `node scripts/post-install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pty.js@0.3.0 postinstall script 'node scripts/post-install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the pty.js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/post-install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pty.js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/apm-install-dir-116511-5876-r9x5dq/npm-debug.log
```

how to fix this? I already installed `pty.js`

## Edit2:

When removing the `sudo` in front of `sudo apm install fonts` I get:

```
apm install fonts
Installing fonts to /home/me/.atom/packages ✗
EACCES, rmdir '/home/me/.atom/packages/fonts'
```

likewise for `terminal-plus`:

```
apm install terminal-plus
Installing terminal-plus to /home/me/.atom/packages ✗
undefined
```

when removing the `sudo` in front of `npm install -g node-gyp` I get:

```
:~$ npm install -g node-gyp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib
└── node-gyp@3.3.1 

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-gyp"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/me/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is related to your problem but is there a need to run `apm install` with `sudo`?

Comment: I think it is also not necessary to run `npm install` with `sudo`. As far as I can tell, the only thing you need to  use `sudo` for is `apt`.

Comment: @edwinksl: did the changes, put the outputs in the edits to the main question

Comment: Ah okay. I went to the GitHub repo, looked at the issues and I saw there are many issues related to your problem. It seems that the maintainer has not responded to them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing PlatformIO IDE, which is a fork of terminal plus (apparently termial-plus is not maintained anymore).

Answer (score 4):

`terminal-plus` is no longer maintained, with its last commit being in November 2015. So I would recommend switching over to my package, [`terminal-fusion`](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-fusion). `terminal-fusion` is a maintained  terminal package for Linux platforms (and only Linux platforms, it won't work on macOS or Windows), that I forked from [`platformio-ide-terminal`](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal). To install it run:

```
$ apm install terminal-fusion --no-confirm
```

where `$` denotes a user console (so do **not** run this command as root). If you experience any issues with `terminal-fusion` please report them at its bug tracker: [here](https://github.com/fusion809/terminal-fusion/issues). If you would like to show your appreciation for my package please star it with APM:

```
$ apm star terminal-fusion
```

and/or with GitHub, by going to its [repository](https://github.com/fusion809/terminal-fusion) and pressing "Star".